# PHPUnit setup before running first test and tear down after running last test

Tags: php, phpunit

I am trying to implement a Django like test utility for a php application using PHPUnit. By Django like, I mean a separate test db is created from the main database before running the first test and it's dropped after running the last test. The test db needs to be created only once even if many test cases are run at a time.

For this, I took the following approach -

I defined a custom test suite class so that I can write the code for creating and dropping the db in its setup and teardown methods and then use this class to run the tests as follows

```
$ phpunit MyTestSuite
```

MyTestSuite defines a static method named `suite` where I just use `glob` and add tests to the testsuite as follows

```
public static function suite() {
    $suite = new MyTestSuite();
    
    foreach (glob('./tests/*Test.php') as $tc) {
        require_once $tc;
        $suite->addTestSuite(basename($tc, '.php'));
    }

    return $suite;
}
```

All Test Case classes extend from a subclass of `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` and the setup and teardown methods of this class take care of loading and clearing initial data from json fixture files.

Now as the no. of tests are increasing, I need to run only a selected tests at a time. But since I am already loading tests using a test suite, the --filter option cannot be used.
This makes me feel that this approach may not have been the correct one.

So my question is, what is the correct approach to do something before running the first test and after running the last test irrespective of how PHPUnit finds them ?

PS: I am not using PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase but my own implementation of creating, populating and dropping the db.

Comment: For single class you could use `setUpBeforeClass` and `tearDownAfterClass` respectively... But for your case. The whole approach looks like it violates one of the major requirements for unit tests: isolation. All the tests should be isolated from each other, and it implies loading fixtures before each test case

Comment: I have mentioned that fixtures are loaded and cleared before and after each test case. But before running the test suite, the actual db the app uses is copied to a test db first and all it's tables are truncated. The code that's tested affects this db. After all tests have been run, it's dropped.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My two spontaneous ideas that don't use `"Test Suites"`. One that does is at the bottom.

###Test Listener

Using [**`PHPUnits test listeners`**](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener) you could do a

```php
  public function startTestSuite(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite $suite)
  {
       if($suite->getName() == "yourDBTests") { // set up db
  }

  public function endTestSuite(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite $suite)
  {
       if($suite->getName() == "yourDBTests") { // tear down db
  }
```

You can define all your DB tests in a testsuite in the xml configuration file like shown [**`in the docs`**](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/organizing-tests.html#organizing-tests.xml-configuration)

```xml
<phpunit>
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="db">
      <dir>/tests/db/</dir>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="unit">
      <dir>/tests/unit/</dir>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

###Bootstrap

Using phpunits bootstrap file you could create a class that creates the DB and tears it down in its own `__destruct` method when the process ends.

Putting the reference to the object in some global scope would ensure the object only gets destructured at the end of all tests. ( As @beanland pointed out: Using register_shutdown_function() makes a whole lot more sense!)

---

##Using Test suites:

http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.2/en/organizing-test-suites.html shows:

```php
<?php

class MySuite extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite
{
    public static function suite()
    {
        return new MySuite('MyTest');
    }

    protected function setUp()
    {
        print "\nMySuite::setUp()";
    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        print "\nMySuite::tearDown()";
    }
}

class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testWorks() {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

this works well in PHPUnit 3.6 and will work in 3.7. It's not in the current docs as the "Test suite classes" are somewhat deprecated/discouraged but they are going to be around for quite some time.

---

Note that tearing down and setting up the whole db for each test case can be quite useful to fight inter-test-dependencies but if you don't run the tests in memory (like sqlite memory)  the speed might not be worth it.

Comment: The Test Listeners method finally worked for me. However, using the bootstrap method throws error `PDOException: You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances` if the db manager instance is assigned to a global variable. Anyway, my problem is solved. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: If you tell phpunit to backup globals (or don't tell it to not do it i should say) it will try to serialize everything in $_GLOBALS. You can ether turn the setting of or don't keep the db connection around but reconnect for shutting everything down :) - Glad it worked though

Comment: The **Test Listener** example is missing a reference for registering the listener in `phpunit.xml` as described here https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html

Comment: This solution is outdated. See post by @total-pusher for a more recent way.

Answer (score 39):

I recently encountered something where I needed to solve the very same issue. I tried [Edorian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10897030/390977) with the `__destruct` method of a custom class, but it seemed to be run at the end of every test rather than at the conclusion of *all* tests.

Instead of using a special class in my bootstrap.php file, I utilized PHP's [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) function to handle database cleanup after the conclusion of all my tests, and it seemed to work perfectly.

Here's an example of what I had in my bootstrap.php file

```
register_shutdown_function(function(){
   some_db_cleanup_methods();
});
```

Comment: Oh yeah. Forgot about that. Makes a whole lot more sense than relying on destruct! Thanks

Comment: was looking for this for like 300 years, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

In 2020 year @edorian's way is already [deprecated](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/4039):

```
/**
 * @throws Exception
 *
 * @deprecated see https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/4039
 */
public function testSuiteLoaderClass(): string
{
    ///
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/cfc60ae52929328b7e261334cb55976147af9493/src/TextUI/XmlConfiguration/PHPUnit/PHPUnit.php#L527)

### New solution

Now we need to use the [TestRunner](https://phpunit-document-english.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending-phpunit.html#extending-the-testrunner) via [extensions](https://phpunit-document-english.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#the-extensions-element). Add this code in `phpunit.xml`:

```
<extensions>
    <extension class="Tests\Extensions\Boot"/>
</extensions>
<testsuites>
  ...
</testsuites>
```

`Tests/Extensions/Boot.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Extensions;

use PHPUnit\Runner\AfterLastTestHook;
use PHPUnit\Runner\BeforeFirstTestHook;

class Boot implements BeforeFirstTestHook, AfterLastTestHook
{
    public function executeBeforeFirstTest(): void
    {
        // phpunit --testsuite Unit
        echo sprintf("testsuite: %s\n", $this->getPhpUnitParam("testsuite"));

        // phpunit --filter CreateCompanyTest
        echo sprintf("filter: %s\n", $this->getPhpUnitParam("filter"));

        echo "TODO: Implement executeBeforeFirstTest() method.";
    }

    public function executeAfterLastTest(): void
    {
        // TODO: Implement executeAfterLastTest() method.
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function getPhpUnitParam(string $paramName): ?string
    {
        global $argv;
        $k = array_search("--$paramName", $argv);
        if (!$k) return null;
        return $argv[$k + 1];
    }
}
```

#### Execution

Pure php:

```
phpunit --testsuite Unit --filter CreateCompanyTest
```

Laravel:

```
php artisan test --testsuite Unit --filter CreateCompanyTest
```

output:

```
PHPUnit 9.3.10 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

testsuite: Unit
filter: CreateCompanyTest
TODO: Implement executeBeforeFirstTest() method.
```

Comment: The documentation links are outdated. Check this: https://phpunit-document-english.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending-phpunit.html