# One time setup and onetime teardown in phpunit

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I'm creating tests in phpunit where I need to set up dummy data in the database. These dummy data will be used throughout all unit test classes so I need to set it up one time only. Currently, I'm setting it up in my base test class `TestCase.php`

To set it up one time I used static variable to check if the one-time setup methods are executed already so even though the setUp() is being called in each test the one-time setup methods will not be called again.

```
abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
     protected static $init = false;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        if (!self::$init) {
            $this->prepareDatabase(); // All insert commands are here...
        }
    }
}
```

My problem here is that I need to clean up these dummy data after all tests are done. Is there a way to execute tearDown() only after ALL tests are done?

Comment: You should write a class that implements `BeforeFirstTestHook` and `AfterLastTestHook` . Instructions on how to do  this are in https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/extending-phpunit.html#extending-the-testrunner however keep in mind that at this point the Laravel app will not have been bootstrapped so you would need to do it manually before you are able to use any Laravel features like the `DB` class or migrations.

Comment: Also keep _process-isolation_ in mind if you want to make use of that Phpunit feature (e.g. by the command-line parameter https://stackoverflow.com/q/9806805/367456).

Comment: @apokryfos can you give another link on how will I use laravel features like DB class inside hooks methods?

Comment: I *think* if you `use CreatesApplication;` (the one from [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/tests/CreatesApplication.php)) and then  run `$app = $this->createApplication();` then from that point on you can use things normally (or you can at least use `$app` for dependency injection)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHPUnit setup before running first test and tear down after running last test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896293/phpunit-setup-before-running-first-test-and-tear-down-after-running-last-test)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to execute tearDown() only after ALL tests are done?

yes,

1. you need to calculate total number of tests in current class, for example in setUpBeforeClass() or when you first time start setUp()
2. set self::$currentTest +1 in setUp() since it called before each test
3. check self::$currentTest in tearDown() and execute what do you need if self::$currentTest = self::$totalTests

---

```
abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    protected static $totalTests = 0;
    protected static $currentTest = 0;

    public static function setUpBeforeClass(): void
    {
        $methods = get_class_methods(static::class);
        self::$totalTests = array_reduce($methods, function($total, $item) {

            if(strpos($item, 'test_') === 0){
                $total++;
            }

            return $total;
        });
    }


    public function setUp() : void 
    {
        parent::setUp();
        self::$currentTest++;
    }

    public function tearDown(): void
    {           

        if(self::$currentTest == self::$totalTests){ // last test

            // do something , i.e. remove models created for your tests
        }

        parent::tearDown();
    }
}
```